# Why I could not install the line_profiler？

Tags: python-3.x

my computer is win10,installed VS2015,python 3.7.3.

when I use jupyter notebook，I found that "%paste" is invalid,the error shows that "UsageError: Line magic function `%paste` not found."
Then I found that the package 'line_profiler' is not installed.
So I install it ,using "pip install line_profiler"
however,many red lines occur.

because I have VS2015,so I could not install visual cpp build tools,which is the answer I have found on sites.
So i dont know how to do with it.
Even it is difficult for me to understand the error information.

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'd:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AMARAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-    install-o1auvf_5\\line-profiler\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AMARAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rymmwo49\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

ERROR: Could not import Cython. Using the available pre-generated C file.

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7

copying line_profiler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7

copying kernprof.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7

copying line_profiler_py35.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7

running build_ext

building '_line_profiler' extension

creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7

creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -
Id:\python\include -Id:\python\include "-IC:\Program Files             (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tc_line_profiler.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\_line_profiler.obj
_line_profiler.c
_line_profiler.c(7890): error C2039: “exc_type”: 不是“_ts”的成员
 _line_profiler.c(7890): error C2039: “exc_type”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7891): error C2039: “exc_value”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7892): error C2039: “exc_traceback”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7899): error C2039: “exc_type”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7900): error C2039: “exc_value”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7901): error C2039: “exc_traceback”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7902): error C2039: “exc_type”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7903): error C2039: “exc_value”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7904): error C2039: “exc_traceback”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7959): error C2039: “exc_type”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7960): error C2039: “exc_value”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7961): error C2039: “exc_traceback”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7962): error C2039: “exc_type”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7963): error C2039: “exc_value”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
_line_profiler.c(7964): error C2039: “exc_traceback”: 不是“_ts”的成员
d:\python\include\pystate.h(212): note: 参见“_ts”的声明
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'d:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AMARAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o1auvf_5\\line-profiler\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AMARAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rymmwo49\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AMARAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o1auvf_5\line-profiler\
```

First,I want to know how to solve the problem.

Second,I want to konw what is wrong.

Third,I want to know what's the meaning of every error,because they are a bit obscure.

PS:"“exc_type”: 不是“_ts”的成员 "means""“exc_type”: is not the member

of“_ts”"

Thank you~